# CentOS 6 with webmin and virtualmin - cant get POP / SMTP working?

Tags: email, centos6

I've set up Webmin and Virtualmin on a CentOS 6 dedicated server.
Postifx / Dovecot config is untouched by me, and I havent tried to open or close any ports manually.

My problem is that after creating a new virtual host and email users for that host, the new email addresses don't seem to be working.

According to nmap, ports 25 and 110 are open, and the MX record and mail.domain.com A record on my domain are all correct, but incoming email isn't getting to the inbox and I can't connect to the SMTP server using a mail client - connection gets refused on port 25. I *seem* to be able to log in to the POP server but none of my test emails have come through.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: ok... any explanation for the downvotes? am I being braindead-stupid or have I asked this question incorrectly?

Comment: alrighty then. *grumble bloody unconstructive downvoters grumble*

Comment: I think the general consensus is that Webmin and Virtualmin aren't meant for full-scale deployment as it can open up new attack surfaces, and also this could have probably been solved by reading some documentation. Don't worry about it too much.

Comment: @tombull89 thanks for clarifying; I did get through most of the virtualmin / webmin docs but they are thin on the ground regarding email setup. doesnt matter, sorted now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my problem was solved by a couple of relatively simple measures:

first, I enabled the `submission` and `smtps` services via servers -> postfix -> server processes; these were both disabled by default.

then, I restarted postfix and dovecot from the command line

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart
sudo /etc/init.d/dovecot restart
```

and my SMTP was suddenly magically working, and the server began accepting external mail too.
This may have been required either because of my changes to the services or perhaps some config changes that were made by Virtualmin when the virtual host was created. Couldn't say for sure but it is working now. Keeping an eye on `/var/log/maillog` in any case.